# Set 2D array and then display as image in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How would I manually set each pixel value in a 2D array and then display this array as an image? I thought this might work, but it hasn't prevailed:

```
for y = 1:1:maxY
    for x = 1:1:maxX
        map{x, y} = %some value
    end
end

newImg = mat2gray(map);
imshow(newImg); title('test');
```

Comment: Use `map(x,y) = value` rather than `map{x, y} = value` since `{}` indexing is for cell arrays only.

Comment: @Suever Thanks, that's fixed it!